# Python multiprocessing.Pool.map_async() does not do all jobs with SparkContext

Tags: python, pyspark, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to convert files from one format to another using the 32 cores that I have. I have this piece of code that should do what I want. I.e. loop through all the files and convert the XML-like files to parquet.  The order does not matter. So, when a job finishes it should simply continue to the next file and convert it without waiting for other jobs. The total number of jobs should not exceed a maximum given in `procs`. It starts very promising, but after the first iteration the process basically stops. I also tried `Pool.map`, `Pool.apply_async`. I am using a pyspark context in a jupyter notebook, not sure whether this is important here.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyteomics import mzxml
from glob import glob

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Pool
from random import shuffle

def mzxml_to_pandas_df(filename):
    slices = []
    file = mzxml.MzXML(filename)
    # print('Reading:', filename)
    while True:
        try:
            slices.append(pd.DataFrame(file.next()))
        except:
            break
    return pd.concat(slices)

def fix_column_names_for_spark(df):
    df.rename(columns={'m/z array': 'mz_array', 
                       'intensity array': 'intensity_array'}, inplace=True)

def mzxml_to_parquet(filename):
    new_name = filename.replace('.mzXML', '.parquet')
    print(new_name, end=" ")
    if os.path.isdir(new_name):
        print('already exists.')
        return None
    df = mzxml_to_pandas_df(filename)
    fix_column_names_for_spark(df)
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(df).write.save(new_name)
    print('done')

mzxml_files = glob('./data/*mzXML')  # list of filenames
procs = 10
pool = Pool(procs)
shuffle(mzxml_files)  # Does not help. 
pool.map_async(mzxml_to_parquet, mzxml_files)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Why would this code stop at some point, not continuing with the remaining files? I am interested in how to properly use multiprocessing, but also, in more elegant ways to do the task. Thanks!

Now, I was able to reproduce these errors. I really seems to be a spark problem:

> ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to
>   the Java server (127.0.0.1:34967) Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "/home/.../software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1145, in send_command
>       self.socket.sendall(command.encode("utf-8")) BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 985, in send_command
>       response = connection.send_command(command)   File "/home/.../software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1149, in send_command
>       "Error while sending", e, proto.ERROR_ON_SEND) py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Error while sending
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 929, in _get_connection
>       connection = self.deque.pop() IndexError: pop from an empty deque
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/.../software/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1067, in start
>       self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port)) ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Does that mean multiprocessing should not be used together with Spark?

Comment: Try `pool.close()` and then `pool.join()`.

Comment: I added it, but still I see it starting with e.g. 10 jobs and then over time the number goes down. Now, it is only one job, now 0. Thought in the jupyter notebook the cell is still busy. Though there are still 1000 files not converted.

Comment: I don't know anything about pyspark, but does it support inheriting an `SQLContext` over a process boundary?  That seems improbable to me.

Comment: At least it works for the first batch of jobs.

Comment: What does the output look like?  Is it printing the new filenames for all of them or only for the first 10?

Comment: Maybe for the first 70 and then it progressively stops.